# Error on website deployment to Azure keystone.js

Tags: node.js, azure, webserver, azure-web-app-service, keystonejs

I am trying to deploy a plain keystone.js starter application built in node.js, to Azure Website's Shared Tier.

I am getting an error after the deployment

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

I thought it might be because the main server file was called `keystone.js` so I renamed it to `index.js`. This didnt fix it.

Next, I thought it could be an issue because keystone defaults to port 3000 so I added in port information in my `index.js` file. Here it is:

```
// Simulate config options from your production environment by
// customising the .env file in your project's root folder.
require('dotenv').load();

// Require keystone
var keystone = require('keystone');

// Initialise Keystone with your project's configuration.
// See http://keystonejs.com/guide/config for available options
// and documentation.

keystone.init({

    'name': 'Magic Site',
    'brand': 'Magic Site',

    'less': 'public',
    'static': 'public',
    'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
    'views': 'templates/views',
    'view engine': 'jade',

    'mongo': "redacted",

    'port': process.env.PORT || 1337,

    'auto update': true,
    'session': true,
    'auth': true,
    'user model': 'User',
    'cookie secret': 'redacted'

});

// Load your project's Models

keystone.import('models');

// Setup common locals for your templates. The following are required for the
// bundled templates and layouts. Any runtime locals (that should be set uniquely
// for each request) should be added to ./routes/middleware.js

keystone.set('locals', {
    _: require('underscore'),
    env: keystone.get('env'),
    utils: keystone.utils,
    editable: keystone.content.editable
});

// Load your project's Routes

keystone.set('routes', require('./routes'));

// Setup common locals for your emails. The following are required by Keystone's
// default email templates, you may remove them if you're using your own.

// Configure the navigation bar in Keystone's Admin UI

keystone.set('nav', {
    'posts': ['posts', 'post-categories'],
    'galleries': 'galleries',
    'enquiries': 'enquiries',
    'users': 'users'
});

// Start Keystone to connect to your database and initialise the web server

keystone.start();
```

Still no luck. However, this works great on my local machine, just not in Azure. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I updated my main server file to be named "server.js". I did some digging and looked at the deployment log in Azure and found this:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Deleting file: 'index.js'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'server.js'
Using start-up script server.js from package.json.
Generated web.config.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29.
Selected node.js version 0.10.29. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
Finished successfully.
```

Comment: how did you upload your project to azure? did you use Kudu? or just copied your contents using FTP ? You will need a web.config to configure iisnode to point to your main script i.e index.js or keystone.js. On you local machine, have you tried this app with iisnode?

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra I have my source code in Bitbucket and I am using Azure websites "deploy from source control" option. I am doing my dev on a mac so I have not used iisnode. Where do I put a web.config file in my project and what do I put in it?

Comment: From the logs above, you should already have web.config automatically created by Kudu. I will try this out myself and let you know my findings. Btw, where have you configured the database?

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra I am using the mongoLab addon in Azure for my database. When running my app locally I can make the mongoLab connection without any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set the platform to 64bit on the configuration tab of your Azure website in the portal. I then created a `IISnode.yml` file at the root of my node project with the following content:

```
loggingEnabled: true
devErrorsEnabled: true
```

Now when I accessed the site via the browser I saw detailed error messages, which showed that the cloudinary env variable wasn't configured. I added the content that was stored in my projects `.env` file to the app settings on the configuration tab of my azure website portal page and that fixed everything!